# Python function argument can't be used as a variable in a child function

Tags: python, function, parameters, global, local

Here's the problem I try to solve:

I have a first function, to which I put in arguments. Then, later on, I have a second function, from which I want to call, as a variable, the said argument of the parent function. So it goes like:

```
def parent_function(argument=x):
 
    if statement:
        child_function()
 
    else:
        ...
 
    return result


def child_function():
 
    x = x + 5
 
    return x
```

If I run such a code, I get an error in the child function saying `name 'x' is not defined`.

However, if I fix my code to make x global in the parent function, like this:

```
def parent_function(argument=x):

    global x

    if statement:
        child_function()
 
    else:
        ...
 
    return result


def child_function():
 
    x = x + 5
 
    return x
```

I get the error `name 'x' is parameter and global`

I need to import both functions in another file and I can't "dismantle" the child function inside the parent function.

Thanks very much for any help !

Comment: can't you pass the value in child function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use global Variables. Every function needs it's own arguments:

```
def parent_function(x):
    if statement:
        x = child_function(x)
    else:
        ...
    return result


def child_function(x):
    x = x + 5
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

`name 'x' is parameter and global` means you can't overwrite parameter `x` for being global also. To fix this, use another variable `y`, like this:

```
def parent_function(argument=x):

    global y
    y = x

    if statement:
        child_function()

    else:
        ...

    return result


def child_function():

    y = y + 5

    return y
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because you are trying to overwrite a parameter in a function whose scope is local to that function by giving it a global scope. The problem is that variables defined in the context of a function are by definition local variables. To better illustrate this problem ,you can simply try to launch this piece of code:

```
def parent_function(argument="Hello"):
    global argument
    return argument
```

You will see that it will fail to run for the same reason that I have explained. I hope I have been clear in my explanation. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to change is this:

```
def parent_function(argument=x):
```

If you search for how to make a default argument in a function you will get something like this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-arguments-in-python/
. This means instead of `x` you need to have some default value, for example:

```
 def parent_function(argument=5):
```

This means that if you do not pass the argument called `argument` to the function value 5 will be passed.
On the other hand, it seems that you want `x` to be an argument, which means the def line should look like this:

```
 def parent_function(x=5):
```

Second, `global` keyword needs to be used in the `child_function` since `x` has not been used in `parent_function`. This leads to this:

```
def parent_function(x=5):

    if statement:
        child_function()
 
    else:
        ...
 
    return result


def child_function():
 
    global x

    x = x + 5
 
    return x
```

To have all this work, there must be at least two more lines one to set `x` and another to call `parent_function`, like this:

```
x = 6
parent_function(4)
```

But, to be even funnier, `x` from the arguments in `parent_function` and `x` used in `child_function` are not the same thing, and you can see for yourself in this example which is similar to your code, but fully executable:

```
def parent_function(x=5):

    if True:
        print(child_function())
 
    else:
        print("else branch")
 
    return True


def child_function():
    global x
 
    x = x + 5
 
    return x

x = 6
parent_function(4)
```

This prints out 11 even you might think it will print out 9!
This is due to fact that keyword `global` refers to the (as the word says) global variable declared outside of the functions, the variable with value 6. Usually, local and global variables should have different names, so either the argument `x` in `parent_function` or global `x` variable needs to be renamed.
IDK if this helps, but you will learn something from this, for sure!